# RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

I'm facing an issue while working on my React Native app. When trying to use the react-native-screens library along with @react-navigation/native-stack, I'm encountering the following error:

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:

```
"RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.
```

This error is located at:

```
in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig (created by HeaderConfig)
in HeaderConfig (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen
in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by AppNavigation)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigation)
in AppNavigation (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in Ai_voice_assistant(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

these are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0"
 }
```

I suspect there might be a compatibility issue or misconfiguration causing this error. Do you have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any guidance on the correct setup or potential fixes would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to run this on iOS? If yes, do pod install and then run the app again. If you are running on Android, do npm run android

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering, "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: 'RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig' was not found in the UIManager," is related to the **react-native-screens** library and its integration with **react-navigation**.

Here are steps to resolve this issue:

> Ensure that the versions of **react-native-screens** and
> **@react-navigation/native-stack** are compatible. Sometimes, specific versions of these packages may have compatibility issues.

> Update the versions of your dependencies to the latest compatible versions, if possible. Check the official documentation for react-native-screens and @react-navigation/native-stack to ensure compatibility between versions.

Update your dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
  "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.72.4",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.8.0"  // Update to a compatible version
}
```

After updating the versions in **package.json**, run the following commands to reinstall the dependencies:

```
npm install
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Sometimes, cached files can cause issues. Clear the build cache by running:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

I hope It will help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy